# Finding the Polar Area of two circles intersecting each other

Tags: calculus, area, polar-coordinates

[image]

The equations for the two circles are:

$r=18\cos{\theta}$

$r=3$

$r_f= 9$ and $r_g=3$

I can see that I need to subtract the $r=3$ circle, however im not sure on how to get the boundaries of integration. 
I set $18\cos{\theta} = 9$ and got $\pi/3$ and $5\pi/3,$ using these boundaries for the equation gives me a wrong number.

It seems like I need help on setting my boundaries. Thanks

Comment: The equation should be $18\cos(\theta) = 3$

Comment: Oh ya, because you are trying to find the point of intersection correct?

Comment: Yep! Then $\cos(\theta) = \frac16$ and it gets ugly.

Comment: Wow thats even uglier than I had before

Comment: Thanks for the help @ChristopherMarley I ended up getting the right answer, but it was definitely ugly.